# Why do I need to redirect $args in nginx to index.php?

Tags: php, redirect, nginx

Many PHP frameworks suggest to add this to nginx :

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

to execute `index.php` on all HTTP requests.

**Why do I need `$is_args$args`?** I think the `$args` are already in the HTTP GET request. So why does nginx need to pass them that way to index.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on who wrote `index.php`. A large number of parameters are sent to PHP from `nginx`, and usually QUERY_STRING and REQUEST_URI are among them.

If the programmer accesses `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` they will receive whatever was appended to the end of `/index.php` in the `try_files` statement.

If the programmer accesses `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` they will receive the original URI together with the original query string, and anything appended to the end of `/index.php` in the `try_files` statement will not affect that.

The two applications that I host (WordPress and MediaWiki) obviously use the latter, because I do not append `$is_args$args` to the `/index.php` and it all works fine.

But another application may behave differently.