# How to redirect on NGINX and store original request as POST variable?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, nginx, server

I'm trying to set up a php site on NGINX. The functionality I'm going for is a way to have a section "expand" without reloading the page, but also being able to store the state in the URL. An example would be this:

1. Click a button to expand a section
2. The section name, say *resume*, would be put in the url: https://example.com/resume **but the site wouldn't reload**
3. If the page is reloaded, the section is expanded by default
4. The when a back button or (X) button is pressed, the url is reverted to https://example.com and the page returns to its original state (without reloading)

I can already add to the url with history.state in my javascript, and I can get the section to expand on the press of a button, but I can't figure out the nginx configuration that will let me reroute all requests for */resume* and a few other ones (like */projects* and */contact*) back to index.php and use the request as a variable in PHP.

I'm pretty sure this would be possible with an .htaccess, but I am using NGINX and trying very hard to avoid using any sort of htaccess file.

My current NGINX config is this:

```
server {
    server {
        root /var/www/example.com/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: A typical NGINX _"friendly URL"_ scheme is to add `/index.php$is_args$args` to your `try_files` configuration (replacing `=404`)

Comment: for storing the state of the UI, I typically use `window.sessionStorage` in Javascript.  Which stores it in the browser, that way it's transparent to the backend and coded where it matter on the front end.  `The functionality I'm going for is a way to have a section "expand" without reloading the page, but also being able to store the state in the URL`  AJAX and `window.sessionStorage` .

Comment: See [Why do I need to redirect $args in nginx to index.php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756038/why-do-i-need-to-redirect-args-in-nginx-to-index-php)